# ubuntuにおける環境問題：symbol lookup error

Tags: c++, ubuntu

ubuntu上でClionを使ってC++のプログラムを開発しています。
昨日までうまく動いていたのですが、今日になって急に次のようなエラーがでるようになりました。

symbol lookup error: /home/********/anaconda3/lib/./libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Blend_CoordinatesProcess finished with exit code 127

「libharfbuzz.so.0」をリンクした覚えはありませんし、ましてやC++なのでanacondaなんで使っていません。
何かの原因で環境が変わってしまったのだと思います。
何かわかる方いますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

追加情報です。
これはどうもawscliをインストールしたときになったようです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 作成されたプログラムが `prog` だとして、`ldd prog` を実行した結果を質問欄に追記していただけますか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「anacondaなんで使っていません」と書いてありますが、anacondaを昨日か今日使ったのではないですか？

anacondaは、自らディストリビューションを名乗っており単なるアプリケーションではなく、`anaconda3/lib`に`libharfbuzz.so.0`のような独自のライブラリを持っていてanacondaを使うときはそれらのライブラリーを使います。その時にPATHを設定して消し忘れるとanacondaの独自のライブラリーが`/usr/lib`等にある本来のライブラリーを乗っ取ってしまいます。

まず、PATHがどうなっているか確認してみましょう。

```
echo $PATH
```

anacondaに関するPATHを全て削除するようにすれば元に戻ると思います。Ubuntuでanacondaを使う場合は、`source anaconda3/bin/activate`を実行するようにするか、anaconda専用のユーザーを作ってそちらでPATHを通すようにするかした方がいいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご質問の回答は、.bashrcファイルの最後に、いつのまにか次の文がそうにゅうされていました。

Comment: # added by Anaconda3 installerexport PATH="/home/flicfit/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

Comment: それでは、よろしくお願いします。